# Android / Libgdx : Detecting multitasking button

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm using Libgdx to develop a game for Android and I noticed that when I press the multitasking button, while I browse the list of the previous apps, the game is still running in background (I can see the game keep moving in the background). Obviously, I'd like to pause the game.

I am using the Screen class and the pause() method seems to be called only when the application is effectively changed. I have not managed to detect the press button event as a workaround.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Whether `pause()` will be invoked in this scenario, is dependent on device/OS.

The key key you want to be listening out for is [KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH). If that doesn't come through with an `InputAdapter` (I don't know the associated `Keys` value, if it even exists), then you need to look into gdx and see why it's not coming through.

Comment: Thanks for the keycode. However, I've added a breakpoint to catch any key in the keyDown InputProcessor and apparently the method is not called when I press this button (but it works for the menu button for instance).